# Freebsd 11 custom installer memstick with packages

Tags: installation, freebsd, shell, automated-install

I use freebsd 11 memstick installer image always but need some packages if I install freebsd 11 then I should install some packages
( phpmyadmin, php7, nginx, mysql, nano) and enabled root ssh vb process

I dont want reagain this process

Can I create customize memstick installer ?

I want include package phpmyadmin, php7, nginx, mysql, nano and change some properties system file on FreeBSD 11 memstick image

how can I do this ?

can u help me ? thank u for help

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way. After booting from memstick, drop into console, optinally `mount -o rw` to remount with read/write permissions, use `gpart resize` and then `growfs` to extend filesystem size. Now `pkg fetch` all packages you need.

This will give you a memstick with required packages on board. After installing a fresh system using it, drop into console, chroot into installed system and use `pkg add` to install them from memstick.